# Dynamic programming algorithm for assigning tasks

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm struggling with this problem. I tried solving it via simple recursion, but the time it takes for the large cases is huge and I'd like to improve it by writing a dynamic programming algorithm.

There are `n` given students and `n` given tasks. Each student is represented by a `1d array of length n` of `0`s and `1`s. `A[i] == 0` means that this student can't accomplish `i`'th task, and `A[i] == 1` means that this student can accomplish `i`'th task. The goal is to determine how many different ways there are to assign tasks to students in a way, that all tasks can be accomplished and single student completes only 1 task.

I'll appreciate any hints on how to approach this problem in a dynamic programming way.

Comment: Example input output for more clearer explanation?

Comment: and what are the bounds for input?

Comment: If you will give the recursion solution I'm sure it will be simple to transfer it to a DP solution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X ?

Answer (score 0):

your problem really look like a matching problem with bipartite graph (Graph Theory), where a student is a node and a task is an other one (from the other ensemble). Edges represent compatibility between them. I don't have any solution in mind but you will be able to find some good stuff about matching problem and dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
    cin>>n;
    int a[n+1][n+1];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
            cin>>a[i][j];
        }
    int dp[(1<<n)];
    memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));
    dp[0]=1;
    for(mask=1;mask<(1<<n);mask++){
        x=getbits(mask);
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                if(mask & (1<<i) && a[x][i+1]){
                    dp[mask]+=dp[mask^(1<<i)];
            }
    }
    cout<<dp[(1<<n)-1];
```

Initialisation condition is dp[0]=1 
so the state of dp is (mask), where x represents that person upto x have been assigned a task which is also equal to setbits of mask, and mask is a binary number, whose each bit represents if that task has been assigned or not.

if i'th bit is not set and x'th person can do that work

```
    dp[mask]+=dp[mask^(1<<i)];
```

Time complexity is O(N*2^N) and Space Complexity O(2^N)